# React Native - Running Parallel Axios / fetch request

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch

**Background:**

I have a React Native project that has to call multiple APIs at the same time (but on different screen). Here's the simplified code.

```
callAPI(method, address, data, callback) {
    console.log("Calling... ", address)

    axios({
      method: method,
      url: address,
      headers: {
        Accept: "text/html",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      data: data
    })
      .then(resp => {
        console.log("Done... ", address)  

        callback(resp.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        callback({
          statusCode: 500,
          errCode: "axios error",
          errmsg: err.message
        })
      })
}


this.callAPI('GET', firstURL, null, callback) // Say, this takes 10 seconds to finish
this.callAPI('GET', secondURL, null, callback) // This takes 1 second
```

Ideally, the secondURL API should return the result regardless whether the firstURL API has finished. However, this is not the case. It will wait for the firstURL API to finish before returning the result of secondURL.

I tried using Axios or fetch, but both of them are waiting for another API call to finish.

I am confused, because I thought Axios and fetch are both promise based?

**Question:**
How do I run two or more API call in parallel in React Native?

**NOTE:**
I can't use Promise.all since I don't necessary call these API together.

**UPDATE**:

- I also found out if the APIs base url are different, it will work as intended. *(e.g. One is https://www.test.com and the another one is https://test.com)*
- I am pretty sure this is a problem with React Native, if I try the same code on jsfiddle.net, it's working as intended

Comment: If you call both of those after each other, and you're not awaiting anything, they should run in parallel. If this is not the case, you have to share more code.

Comment: @Evert I have updated my question with the callAPI method

Comment: Normally the code you shared would *not* wait for each other. The issue *must* lie somewhere unrelated to the code you shared.

Comment: @Evert the thing is, when I call both of the API, the Calling... line is executed simultaneously. However, the Done.. line will wait for each other. I am pretty sure these are all the codes that have the problem. I am not using Async Await on the code.

Comment: Do both requests show up right away in your browser network tab?

Comment: @Evert I used React Native Debugger to see the network requests, and yes, all of the requests show up immediately when called.

Comment: Then I suspect that it's not the client that's blocking, but the server!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235639/discussion-between-the1993-and-evert).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Evert, this is a problem with the server. The server was blocking other APIs to be executed concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) and handling your network requests with Redux. This is a bit of a complicated subject so i'd look into Redux on your own, but generally, the strategy is to dispatch the actions corresponding to your callAPI function and then store their results in your app state. Part of the beauty of AsyncThunks are that you have access to the lifecycle methods of the async calls (pending, fulfilled, rejected).